# How do I specify the tables using XlCmdType.xlCmdTableCollection for an Excel Data Model connection in C# / VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Using Connections.Add2 throws an invalid argument exception for the commandText "Table1, Table2,..."

```
var dataModel = application.ActiveWorkbook.Model;            
var workBookConnection = application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2("Sample Connection", "Sample Description", connectionString, "Product, ProductCategory", XlCmdType.xlCmdTableCollection, true, true);   
dataModel.AddConnection(workBookConnection);
```

Comment: CreateModelConnection was true so no need for dataModel.AddConnection.

var workBookConnection = application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2("Sample Connection", "Sample Description", connectionString, new[] { "[Production].[Location]" }, XlCmdType.xlCmdTableCollection, true, true);

System.ArgumentException: 'The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))'

Comment: This also failed: var tables = new[] { "[Production].[Location]" };
            var workBookConnection = application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2("Sample Connection", "Sample Description", connectionString, string.Join(",", tables), XlCmdType.xlCmdTableCollection, true, true);

Comment: Specifying Provider=sqloledb; in connection string also did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
var tables = new[] { "Product" };
            var cs = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2019;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            var workBookConnection = application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2("Sample Connection", "Sample Description", cs, string.Join(",", tables), XlCmdType.xlCmdTableCollection, true, true);
```